# Groupby an numpy.array based on groupby of a pandas.DataFrame with the same length

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a numpy.array `arr` and a pandas.DataFrame `df`.

`arr` and `df` have the same shape `(x,y)`.

I need to group by one column of `df` and apply the transformation of the impacted rows on `arr` which have the same shape.

To be clear, here is a toy example:

```py
arr = 
   0  1   12   3
   2  5   45   47
   3  19  11  111

df =
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  4  9  10  11
```

I want to group `df` by `A` and compute the mean but in place of transforming `df` I want `arr` to be transformed.

So I get something like:

```py
    arr = 
        0        1         12          3
       (2+3)/2  (5+19)/2   (45+11)/2   (47+111)/2
```

Is that  possible? With no expensive loops?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like need first create `DataFrame` from `arr`, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `A` and aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html). Last convert it to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby(df.A).mean().values)
[[  0.    1.   12.    3. ]
 [  2.5  12.   28.   79. ]]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, but what if I want to group by multiple columns?

Comment: If need multiple columns, try `(pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby([df.A, df.B]).mean().values)`

Comment: That's just awsome!  +1

Comment: thank you! as I am new with the `groupby()` method I hve asked an other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849639/panda-dataframe-groupby-wierd-behaviour-with-numpy-array?noredirect=1#comment65064214_38849639 any help? thank you again