# Panda DataFrame.groupby() wierd behaviour with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a very big dataframe that I can't put here unlikely for a demonstration but I am wondering if there is an explanation for a problem I have with my code using `groupby()` method.

So, let `df` be a numeric `pandas.DataFrame` with `(11815, 409)` as shape.

Let `arr = df.as_matrix().astype(float)`.

Why I have this??

```py
print df.groupby(["col1","col2"]).mean().reset_index().shape
>> (624, 409)
```

While:

```py
print pandas.DataFrame(arr).groupby([df["col1"],df["col2"]]).mean().values().shape
>> (623, 409)
```

Note THAT this problem show up also with `["col1","col2","col3"]` BUT don't occur with `["col2","col3"]`,`"col1"`, `"col2"` and `"col3"`.

So, there is a problem with 'col1' but what it can be??

Any explanation please??

Comment: try not using `reset_index()`, what's the result?

Comment: can you post an output of: `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @danielhadar same result for the number of rows :/ `reset_index()` just reset the number of columns

Comment: @MaxU it's all `float64`

Comment: could it be that in the second option `df["col2"]` is taken as the 2nd argument of `groupby`? try giving `groupby` the same format in both options

Comment: @farhawa, what is the point of doing casting if they are already floats: `.astype(float)`?

Comment: @MaxU: True, it's useless :)

Comment: cool, let's try some other stuff. did you check if the `DataFrame` constructed from `pandas.DataFrame(arr)` is the same as the original `df`?

Comment: can you post an output of: `(df.values == arr).all()`?

Comment: @dani, yes ! same shape

Comment: @MaxU: False !! it's wierd

Comment: @farhawa, that explains your problem. Try to get rid of casting `.astype(float)` and re-run your code

Comment: @MaxU, I answered on your first comment ( before the edit ), so `(df.values == arr).all()` give `True`

Comment: so your problem is fixed now?

Comment: No... As there is no different data between `arr` and `df` I still don"t know what is the problem :/

Comment: @farhawa, i guess you woud need to give us sample data set, which might help to reproduce this problem...